# How to prevent raphaeljs from opening images in new tab on mouseclick+ctrldown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I'm working on raphaeljs based web app.
I used both mouseclick & ctrl down events as input.
But as it turns out when you click onto an image element while ctrl key is down, it opens the image in a new browser tab.

Check it out (mouse click onto image while ctrl key is pressed):

```
<div id="canvas" style="width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
<script>
   paper=Raphael("canvas",400,400);
    paper.image("https://www.google.com/logos/2011/twain11-sr.png",20,20,100,100);
</script>
```

How to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried binding click events on this image through this libray, jQuery or with js.

```
$('svg img').click(function(){
return false;
});
```